# Why is CloudFormation saying AlreadyExists when creating a AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have an existing Lambda function called `My-Authorizer`. I'm trying to deploy an API Gateway using Serverless, with CloudFormation (CF) resources, one of which is an authorizer that targets this Lambda.

```
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: "${self:service}-test"

  # other resources

  MyAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    DependsOn: ApiGateway
    Properties:
      Name: My-Authorizer
      Type: REQUEST
      RestApiId:
        Ref: ApiGateway
      AuthorizerUri: "arn:aws:apigateway:${self:custom.aws_region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.aws_region}:${self:custom.aws_account_id}:function:My-Authorizer/invocations"
```

But CF gives a `CREATE_FAILED` for `MyAuthorizer` with the following Status reason:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request input (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: <some-request-id>)" (RequestToken: <some-request-token>, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
```

I've checked that `MyAuthorizer` is not already a resource in this stack.

**Question:** Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that works.

I don't think there is a way to achieve this using `AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer` and a Lambda function that already exists in your account. If you are deploying a new function however, then this may work.

Instead, I exported a dummy API Gateway (Export as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions) that I created via the console, which has all the authorisation configuration I require. I then did this:

```
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: "${self:service}-test"
      Body:
        <exported YAML from above>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is due to authorization caching is enabled by default and thus **IdentitySource** property is required by default. Specifying **IdentitySource** property or disabling authorization caching will fix the issue (see Edit 2 below).

Original (6/29/2022):

I experienced the same issue and after spending hours, I managed to solve it by adding **IdentitySource** property even though it is marked as required only when authorization caching is enabled. What leads me to the solution is the word "Invalid Request". And my authorizer looks like the following:

```
Resources:
  APIGWAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: apigw-authorizer
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization # customize to your need
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizerUri: # arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{LambdaFunctionARN}/invocations
      Type: REQUEST
```

Edit 1 (6/29/2022):

It automatically enabled authorization caching for me. The weird thing is I'm able to remove **IdentitySource** property and successfully update the stack. However, that didn't remove the actual Identity Source nor the Authorization Caching. So, I had to add AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds property to disable the caching. And thus, to disable the caching, it becomes:

```
Resources:
  APIGWAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: apigw-authorizer
      AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization # customize to your need
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizerUri: # arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{LambdaFunctionARN}/invocations
      Type: REQUEST
```

Edit 2 (6/30/2022):

Found out that AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds defaults to 300 is causing the error. So by default, authorization caching is enabled and thus **IdentitySource** property is actually required by default. I'm able to create a new authorizer without specifying IdentitySource property but it requires disabling the authorization caching.

```
Resources:
  APIGWAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: apigw-authorizer
      AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0 # disable authorization caching
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizerUri: # arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{LambdaFunctionARN}/invocations
      Type: REQUEST
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html

Comment: Thanks for that. Hm, caching/TTL seem like completely unrelated issues, so I'm surprised these have a bearing on the problem. Are you sure your Lambda function already exists at the time of creating your `APIGWAuthorizer` resource? What's the value of your `{LambdaFunctionARN}`? My config has changed significantly so I'm unable to test this straight away.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that my lambda already existed when I create the authorizer. We have multiple APIs that share the function as authorizer. For the Lambda Arn, it is just a regular Lambda Arn (in my case, output from other CFn stack) e.g. arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:myfunctionname. I think the AuthorizerUri property info in HTTP API makes it clearer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-authorizer.html

Comment: Disabling the cache worked for me first try.

Answer (score 0):

> I've checked that MyAuthorizer is not already a resource in this stack.

It does not have to be in the stack. It may be in your account somewhere, created manually using AWS console or other CloudFormation stack. You have to change the name of your `MyAuthorizer` to be unique.

Comment: Hm, not sure I follow. The lambda named `My-Authorizer` (as seen in the ARN) is existing and was created via the AWS console. It's this lambda that I need triggered by the authoriser I'm trying to create, so how can I (re)use it? I changed it to `Name: My-Other-Authorizer` (just in case that's what you meant) but it still failed with the same error.

Comment: @Ash It can be failing with the same error, unless your name is again not unique.

Comment: The name (`My-Other-Authorizer` in this case) is most definitely unique, there is nothing in the entire AWS account with that name. The `AuthorizerUri` still however points to the original (existing) lambda `My-Authorizer`.